# Disappear border in a specific row in a table

Tags: css, asp.net, row, border, css-tables

How can I disappear the last border in specific row, for example:

This code below:

```
 <style> //The CSS
     .tdSpace {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            width:3px;
            border:1px solid white;        
            }

       .tdIzq  { // I use this style to add space between two rows
            background: #FFFFFF;
            color: #333333;
            font: small "arial";
            border:1px solid white;
            border-right:solid #E1E1E1;
            border-left:solid #7AC142;         
            border-width:1px;  
            border-left-width:2px;      
            }

           .tdIzq2  {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            color: #333333;
            font: small "arial";
            border:0px solid white;
            border-right:solid #E1E1E1;
            border-left:solid #7AC142;         
            border-width:1px;  
            border-left-width:2px;  
            text-align:right;    
            }

         .tdSueldo  {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            color: #333333;
            font: small "arial";
            border:1px solid white;
            border-right:solid #7AC142;
            border-left:solid #7AC142;         
            border-width:2px;  
            text-align:right; 
            }

      .GvGrid tr:hover
        {
            background-color: #000;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

      #GvGrid tr.rowHover:hover
        {

            background-color: Yellow;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

    .GvGrid th {
            background: #7AC142;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size:12px;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            font-weight:bold;
            width: 60px;
            }
 </style>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPDatos" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table id="TblCom" runat="server" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:GridView ID="Gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static" RowStyle-CssClass="GvGrid" CellPadding="1">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GvGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <Columns>
                                   <asp:BoundField DataField="UTILIDAD_BRUTA" HeaderText="U.B." DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" CssClass="tdDer"/>
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField>
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Width="1px" />
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="tdSeparador" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="COMISION MAYOR" DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                                         <ItemStyle Width="50px" CssClass="tdSueldo" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField>
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Width="1px" />
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="tdSeparador"/>
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="SALES" HeaderText="SALES" DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                                        <ItemStyle Width="70px" CssClass="tdIzq2" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="COM" HeaderText="COM" DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                                         <ItemStyle Width="70px" CssClass="tdDinero" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="TOTAL" DataFormatString="{0:N2}">
                                       <ItemStyle Width="70px" CssClass="tdDer"/>
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>                               
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The colums I need to disappear only the last `<td>` border-bottom in the = CssClass="tdSeparador", I try using the next code:

```
            .tdSpace {
              background-color: #FFFFFF;
              border-bottom: 10px solid black;  
              border-right-style:solid;  
              border-left-style:solid;
             }
```

The problem was disappear in every td, I attach an image:

[image: Disappear onlye the border-bottom in a specific colum]

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-bottom:none;` instead

Comment: I try but not functions the code above any other idea or suggestion?